# How to make an hybrid environment paragraph/equation?

Tags: equations, paragraphs, text, hyperlink

I would like to reproduce the text below which in you can see that some text paragraphs are treated like equations, with a label. I want to create hyperlinks to, has in :

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{$C_1$}\label{C1} \text{My paragraph within a equation structure}
\end{equation}
I can now refer to \eqref {C1}.
```

This structure is ok, I guess, for a small sentences, but how to deal with such a text :

[image]

Comment: Use a `\parbox`, as in: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tag{$C_1$}\label{C1} \parbox[t]{1in}{My paragraph within a equation structure}
\end{equation}
I can now refer to \eqref {C1}.   
\end{document}`.  However, I think there are better ways than with an equation.

Comment: Why not use a custom description environment?

Comment: @Bernard It is an appealing idea, but how can I make a hyperlink? Because, for instance, with ```\begin{description}
\item[($C_1$)]\label{C1}....```, the reference doesn't follow...